# Python pandas extract, how to extract remaining part of string

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have looked for hours and this should be simple. I am trying to extract all the letters from a string with a mixture or digits and letters. Here is an example:

```
df = pd.Series(['ENGLANDSR11SW'])
df = df.to_frame('column')
df['ValueAfterExtract'] = df['column'].str.extract("(?P<letter>[a-zA-Z]+)")
print(df)
```

From the string value `ENGLANDSR11SW` in the dataframe, the result is `ENGLANDSR` but i want to bring even the last letters of the string which is the `SW` which should result in `ENGLANDSRSW` , meaning only the digits `11` would be removed.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all digits (`\d`) with empty strings:

```
In [6]: df['column'].str.replace(r'\d', '')
Out[10]: 
0    ENGLANDSRSW
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Or, to remove everything which is not in `[a-zA-Z]` use the regexp `[^a-zA-Z]`. This would remove, for instance, whitespace and punctuation marks as well as digits:

```
In [20]: df['column'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '')
Out[20]: 
0    ENGLANDSRSW
Name: column, dtype: object
```